# Use IF to check imagelocation value of a picturebox

Tags: winforms, picturebox

To let you know, I'm using the visual basic winform coding.

AND I'm using visual studio community 2015.

I know how to use the "if" command like this:

```
If TextBox1.Text = "hi" Then
  Label1.Text = "TEST"
End If
```

I also know I can have ifs with ifs inside them

```
If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
  If Label1.Text = "hi" then
    Label2.Text = "TEST"
  End If
End If
```

but when I try to use it with picturebox's it doesn't work:

```
If PictureBox1.ImageLocation = "C:\blok\grass.png" Then
  Label1.Text = "TEST"
End If
```

when the program runs, it ignores it, is there an alternative way to do this?

UPDATE 1.1

so, to let you know, somebody told me there was no picturebox1.imagelocation, but if that's the case, then how does this work:

```
    if label1.text = "TEST" then
picturebox1.imagelocation = "C:\users\TEST\destop\TEST.png"
    end if
```

so yeah.... theres the first update. also to edit this I had to reset my password, luckly I wrote it down so I can remember.

UPDATE 1.2

don't worry, I figured it out! it goes like this:

```
public class form1
dim IMAGE as integer = 1
private sub button1_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs Handles)  button1.Click
if IMAGE = 1 then
picturebox1.imagelocation = "C:\TEST.png"
end if
end sub
end class
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: visual studio code.

Comment: …that's not a language, it's an editor. Is this maybe VB.NET?

Comment: oh... well when I say visual studio I think of "visual basic" coding.

Comment: the forms application coding

Comment: 'when I say visual studio I think of "visual basic" coding'—well, you shouldn't. Visual Studio Code supports a huge number of languages. Is this Visual Basic, or VB.NET? Or maybe VBA?

Comment: its visual basic.

Comment: I don't use VB.net and don't really know what VBA is.

Comment: VBA is Visual Basic for Applications; it's used to create macros in Microsoft Office, for example.

Comment: This is not VB6, the VB6 picturebox control does not have an imagelocation property.  VB.net does have the imagelocation property on the picturebox control.  It will return the current path and filename for the image in the control.  The string comparison is case sensitive, so that could be why your test isn't working as you think it should be. Try displaying the value before the test to check what the value is: `MessageBox.Show (picturebox1.imagelocation)`.

Comment: Yes, this smells like Visual Fred, not VB.  Wrong tag.

Comment: Regardless of the language, you will need to be careful about the comparison for at least two reasons. Firstly case will be significant unless you use a case-insensitive compare function, and second the backslashes in the comparison string may be seen by the language as escape characters. I edited your question and added the VB.Net tag in the hope that someone with knowledge can confirm.

Comment: Can't you debug your code ?
See the value of PictureBox1.ImageLocation and see why your condition isn't true.

Comment: @HunterWolf `I don't use VB.net and don't really know what VBA is.`
The code in your question is VB.NET :)

Comment: When you will change the `Label1`'s text to `"TEST"`?

Comment: Youssef I don't use VB.NET, I use the regular forms application.

Comment: MarkL I see.... so the forms application (visual basic code) doesent have picturebox1.imagelocation but VB.NET does? hmm.....

Comment: oh yea, and someone put VB.NET on my question without permission, I don't use VB.NET so someone had to of put it there. sorry for the clump o` comments.

Comment: don't worry! I got it solved!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class form1
dim IMAGE as integer = 1
private sub button1_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs Handles) button1.Click
if IMAGE = 1 then
picturebox1.imagelocation = "C:\TEST.png"
end if
end sub
end class
```

by doing this, when you click the button, it will show the picturebox.